# Short way to determine today's unix time without considering the hour, minute, or second?

Tags: javascript, datetime

I need to find unix day for today. Previously, I did it like this:

```
const today = new Date();
const todayUnixDay = Date.parse((today.getMonth()+1) + '/' + today.getDate() + '/' + today.getFullYear());
```

Is there a cleaner way? Maybe using moment? I am not sure how to proceed.

EDIT:
I want only the day, month, and year to be considered when calculating unix, not second, minute, and hour.

Answer (score 0):

To get the start of the day, use [*setHours*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours), or start of the UTC day use [*setUTCHours*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setUTCHours). Both return the time value of the modified date, which is milliseconds since 1970-01-01 (the ECMAScript epoch).

*getHours* will set the date to the start of the local day, *setUTCHours* will set the date to the start of the UTC day. If by "UNIX time" you mean seconds since the same epoch, then you also need to divide by 1,000.

E.g.

```js
let localSOD = new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0);
let unixSOD = new Date().setUTCHours(0,0,0,0)/1000;

console.log('Time values for start of day' +
          '\nLocal (milliseconds) : ' + localSOD + 
          '\nUNIX UTC (seconds)   :    ' + unixSOD);
```